# MSSQL index between two dates

Tags: sql-server

I have a table that consist of many columns, among them two dates (startDate and endDate).

The table contains 15.000.000 records.

My query is is setup like this

```
SELECT ID FROM table WHERE @inputdate BETWEEN startDate and endDate
```

How should my index be setup to maximize performance?

Comment: CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [UIX_TABLE_StartDateEndDate] ON [dbo].[TABLE]([StartDate] ASC, [EndDate] ASC) INCLUDE([ID]) is a good start. To maximize performance you must profile the load and maybe you can improve it with minor tweeks

Comment: Tell us more about your data. What is the interval between start and end? Is it limited (e.g. both on same, day, or same week) or can it be anything, like years?

Answer (score 2):

To extend my comment to an answer.

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX
[UIX_TABLE_StartDateEndDate]
 ON [dbo].[TABLE]
 ([StartDate] ASC, [EndDate] ASC)
 INCLUDE([ID])
```

Is a good start. To maximize performance you must profile the load and maybe you can improve it with minor tweeks like setting fillfactor padding etc.

Another good choose from start is if your date columns are nullable and you never search for the null values. That way you can apply a filter to the index like

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX
    [UIX_TABLE_StartDateEndDate]
     ON [dbo].[TABLE]
     ([StartDate] ASC, [EndDate] ASC)
     INCLUDE([ID])
WHERE ([StartDate] IS NOT NULL AND [EndDate] IS NOT NULL)
```